# macOS Catalina Having to execute source ~/.bashrc so that I can use mysql commands

Tags: mysql, bash, terminal

Sorry if I come off as a bit naive to this question - I am not at all familiar with bash nor anything about it so I will try to explain my situation the best I can so bare with me here. I installed mysql v5.7 through `brew install` which worked out fine. I then couldn't execute any of the mysql commands in the terminal and would get `-bash: mysql: command not found`. So I dug a little deeper and it seemed like the file path for mysql commands was not one of the ones that started up with my terminal so I then executed `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7:PATH"' >> ~/bashrc`. But even when I tried again the commands wouldn't work, I restarted the terminal and still no luck. I discovered that I could execute it manually by using `source ~/.bashrc`. This finally worked for me but now I'm stuck with the problem of having to execute `source ~/.bashrc` everytime I want to be able to use mysql. Does anyone know what is going on here and why it won't execute upon terminal start up?

Comment: The default shell in Catalina is zsh; did you  change yours to Bash? If not, you need to use `~/.zshrc` to get you MySQL commands loading on shell startup. Bash shell code will not always be compatible, and so even just sourcing `~/.bashrc` could cause issues.

Comment: If you typed that command exactly as given above, it'll thoroughly mess up the `PATH` in any shells that run `.bashrc` (i.e. non-login interactive bash shells). You need a `$` before the `PATH` at the end (`.../mysql@5.7:$PATH"'...`). Without that, your shell will not be able to find any commands *except* the mysql ones.

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis : When you run an executable, you either have to specify the directory fully, when calling the program, or put the directory into the `PATH`. If you don't want to type the `PATH=....` assignment everytime you open a new shell, use your text editor to create files `~/.bash_profile` and `/.bashrc. The former is processed by bash if it is an interactive login shell, and the latter if it is a interactive non-login shell. Programs for setting up the shell are placed here. Then start a new shell, to have the settings available.

Comment: @I3I_aze : Zsh is not relevant here. You can see from the error message that the OP got, that he is running bash.

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis : Have a look at `man bash`, in pratiular to the section titled **INVOCATION**, which explains what is going on when bash starts.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone ever happens to come across this. Mac OS X does not run `~/.bashrc` on terminal start up so any file paths located there will not start which is why I had to do `source ~/.bashrc` every time. I fixed the issue by putting my file paths into `~/.bash_profile` which does run on terminal start up, and fixed my issue.

Comment: this has nothing to do with MacOSX, but to bash and to the way you define the command to be executed when you open a shell from your terminal application. You  as the user can basically choose freely, how bash should behave. A frequently used setup is to create a file, say,  `~/.interactive`, which you source from `.bash_profile` **and** from `.bashrc` to make sure that the settings apply in every new interactive shell, whether it is a login-shell or not.

Comment: You are incorrect. It has everything to do with the way Mac OSX. It doesn't read `.bashrc` file on bash start up like I said. Per the documentation from apple themselves `By default, Terminal starts the shell via /usr/bin/login, which makes the shell a login shell. On every platform (not just Mac OS X) bash does not use .bashrc for login shells (only /etc/profile and the first of .bash_profile, .bash_login, .profile that exists and is readable). This is why "put source ~/.bashrc in your .bash_profile" is standard advice`

Comment: `.bashrc` is not read by login shells. From the bash manpage: _When an interactive shell that is **not a login** shell is started, bash reads and  executes  commands  from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists._. One common solution is to have bash set up as a login shell, and configure the terminal application to start a bash which is not a login shell. If the system is configured so that your applications start from your login shell, this runs your `.bash_profile` and when you start a child shell from your terminal, you get `.bashrc` executing.